# Vuejs and HTML5 Gamepad API: How to render Gamepad Object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gamepad-api

I'm trying to list available gamepads and select a gamepad in available gamepads. When `select this gamepad` button pressed gamepads list will be not visible and only selected gamepad will be visible.

I tried to do this with `v-if`:

```
<div v-if="selectedGamepad != null">
  {{selectedGamepad.axes}}
</div>
<div v-if="selectedGamepad == null">
  <div class="gamepad" v-for="gamepad in gamepads">
    {{gamepad.id}}
    <button v-on:click="selectedGamepad = gamepad;">Select This Gamepad</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I press the button `selectedGamepad` values not change dynamically. Because when I press the button, Vuejs not render the `gamepads loop`.

But if `gamepads loop` visible `selectedGamepad` values changes dynamically.(if you remove `v-if` on `gamepads loop`)

I don't understand why `v-for="gamepad in gamepads"` effect to `selectedGamepad`.

If I use `v-show` instead of `v-if` everything works fine but I don't want to render `gamepads` after button pressed.

You can see full example from here : https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/518811/

I think the problem is related to the `Gamepad` object. If `selectedGamepad` is a `Gamepad` object Vuejs can't render dynamically. But if `selectedGamepad` is a `array`(axes array for example) everything works fine. But i can't figure out how to render `Gamepad` object correctly.

Comment: When I click the button, `selectedGamepad` changes from `null` to whatever `event.gamepad` is for that gamepad. Exactly as exptected, the loop disappears and I see the value of `{{selectedGamepad.axes}}` instead. What exactly is not working as intended?

Comment: But axis values not change when move the gamepad joysticks. Actually its change but vue not render the new values in view.

Comment: It sounds like vue was not able to modify the object to inject it's getters/setters needed for invalidating (eg, knowing when the values have changed)

Comment: I just tried your demo with two Joy-Con controllers and it showed the axes (an array of four values) as expected.